# CSV Reader not opening file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read the rows of a CSV file and print each row, but the code I've been using isn't opening the file or running the FOR loop. Any ideas?

```
import csv
domainFile = 'magtest.csv'
f = open(domainFile, 'ab+')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print "file opened"
    for row in reader:
        print "Read domain: %s" %row
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

`ab+` mode opens a file for both appending and binary format, so therefore you cannot read in the contents if it is open to be appended to, you want `r` to read it:

```
f = open(domainFile, 'r')
```

For more information about all of the different file modes, please [refer to this documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: For more information on file open and modes, see the documentation here:   https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @Symmitchry I was trying to look for a list like that, thanks

Comment: Ah! What a rookie mistake. Thanks for catching that, everything works now.